# How do I find the lowest $k$ for which a graph is $k$-partite?

Tags: graph-theory

An undirected graph is bipartite if its vertices can divided into two non-empty sets for which no two vertices in the same set have an edge with each other. We can test if a graph is bipartite by doing a breadth first search and alternating the label that we assign each layer of vertices.

How can I find the smallest $k$ such that I can divide a graph into $k$ sets and no vertices within any of the sets have an edge with each other?

Could this problem be reduced to negating the edges in the graph (turning edges into non-edges and turning non-edges into edges) and then listing the maximal cliques in the graph?

I'm trying to reduce this problem into a format that can be tackled with say dynamic programming in polynomial time.

Comment: You can reduce it to negating the edges in the graph, and then listing the -minimal- cliques in the graph, if that helps you. Recall that in the complement graph of H (the graph with negating edges), every indepent set turns into a clique and vice versa.

Comment: Wow, nice! Like you said, it seems I can reduce the problem to finding the minimal  number of cliques I can divide the graph into. At least the decision version of the problem is NP-complete - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover_problem

Do you know of a dynamic programming method for solving the minimizing problem?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but aren't you asking about the chromatic number of a graph?

Comment: He is asking about the chromatic number of a graph. If you would like david I can summarise the rules I know about specific type of graphs and their chromatic numbers, however I am no computer man yet, I do not know any dynamic programming method for such. I suggest you ask that question at stackoverflow.

Comment: There is no way to solve this problem in polynomial time. There are various ways to approach this problem depending on the real motivation of this question.

Comment: Generally true, unless of course you work on a specific type of Graphs, with certain limitations and rules, than there might be a fine way to approach it so it can be solved in a polynomial time, I believe.

Comment: Ok, here's my underlying motivation. :) I'm writing a script to plan events for a conference. The times (but not the days) of each event are set in stone, so for instance, we know event $e$ must occur from 1pm to 3pm on some day. My script will determine the fewest number of days we can make the conference happen given that no events can overlap. My first attempt is to model the problem with an undirected graph with events being vertices. Edges between vertices occur if two events overlap (and thus cannot occur on the same day). Does that make the problem more feasible? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and all events occur within a day, so no event intervals cross 12am or span multiple days.